# WHERE clause based on part of a VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I need to search the numerical part of a string in SQL Server.

[image]

In the number column above needs to be searchable as a variable in the query.

Wildcards does not work:

```
SELECT PK_Story 
FROM Story 
WHERE ProductId = @productParam 
  AND Number LIKE '%' + @numberParam + '%';
```

because this would also return 132 and 232 for example.

So how can I search for a specific number after the '-'. As you can see I can't do charindex because of the variable prefix length.

Comment: When you find yourself needing to do things like this, it points to a design problem. Specifically, you're jamming two pieces of information (i.e. product name and id) into one column. Split them out and either create a computed column or use more than one predicate when searching (i.e. `where ProductName = 'MISCX' and ID = 212'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `LIKE '%-' + @numberParam`?

Comment: maybe drop the last % so MISCX-321 wouldn't be returned?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring` and `charindex` combination to get the result.

```
SELECT PK_Story 
FROM Story
WHERE ProductId = @productParam 
AND @numberParam like 
'%' + case when charindex('-', Number) > 0 
           then substring(Number, charindex('-', Number) +1, len(Number)) + '%'
      else Number 
      end + '%'
```

Comment: this still returns multiple entries for 32 it also pulls in 132

Comment: what is the `@numberParam` you are passing in? and what do you expect as the result? you might have to remove either the leading or trailing `%` accordingly

Comment: You have to make the substring on the column, not on the parameter. `substring(number, charindex('-', number) +1, len(@numberParam)) = @numberParam`

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
declare @My_Number as varchar(50)='8'

SELECT PK_Story 
FROM Story
WHERE ProductId = @productParam 
AND substring(Number, charindex('-', Number) +1, len(Number)) like 
@My_Number +'%'
```

Or, if want equal

```
SELECT PK_Story 
    FROM Story
    WHERE ProductId = @productParam 
    AND substring(Number, charindex('-', Number) +1, len(Number)) =
    @My_Numbe
```

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate Answer?? @MajidKalkatechi
will you please explain??